# Start infinite loop automatically with WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, infinite-loop

I have a WCf service. AMong with several services I need to write a piece of code that always check for updates in a SAP table and update a SQL Server database.

This function need to start when the server starts and should never stop.

I tried to use  AppInitialize, but when the service starts it never get past this code.

What should I do?

Comment: Could please update your answer with your current source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a separate thread to run this function. See [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx).

Comment: Note that most of the time you probably want to use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` to create a background thread.

Comment: My WCF service don`t have a main class, where should I create the Thread?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create a windows service and have it do this.  If you are hosting your WCF services in IIS right now it can shutdown your AppPool etc. when ever it wants.

There is a windows service project type in Visual Studio that makes this easy to do.

Comment: Thats what I want. U know wich service type?